# Java:Overriding a static function

Tags: java

What should be printed when we execute this code?
I picked the question from [here](http://geeksquiz.com/java/inheritance-2/) where the answer is provided but I kinda believe is wrong. First the call to a static function has to be done in static way, second when we override a static function the previous one is no longer accessible ( no new memory is assigned)

```
class Base {
    public static void show() {
       System.out.println("Base::show() called");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public static void show() {
       System.out.println("Derived::show() called");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b = new Derived();;
        b.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `static` method never `overrides`

Comment: "_What should be printed when we execute this code?_" Can't you just execute it and see?

Comment: Check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) link by Oracle

Answer (score 0):

`static` method belongs to class itself and overriding works for instance methods only. If you define the same method again in sub-class then it's called <strike>re-defining</strike> hiding of the `static` method.

`static` method looks for class to invoke it and that can be verified by below same code:

```
Base b = null;
b.show();  // Base::show() called
```

It doesn't make any sense to call `static` method via object.

Comment: Actually, it's called "hiding". Not "redefining". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks let me read.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for correcting me. Most of time I read in books about redefining. May be they used wrong term.